# Some websites load while others load forever in Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux, networking

I have installed Linux Mint 18 64 bit and noticed google and youtube and others loading flawlessly (even HD videos play) but some sites like wikipedia don't show up even though the tabs in mozilla either show "loading" or show "wikipedia - the free encyclopedia" but then the site doesn't appear.

The computer loads some sites but doesn't load others, and they don't change - if site A doesn't load then it doesn't load next time either. If site B loads then it loads afterwards too.

Last time I checked the internet connection in a different computer - with windows - everything worked, so it's not ISP's fault.

It does this even with ufw disabled.

Doesn't work with Mint liveDVD either. It's the same thing.

If I open up a web proxy and type in wikipedia then it goes there.

Same thing with other browsers.

After typing wget wikipedia.org:

```
--2016-07-20 21:30:40--  htt.p://wikipedia.org/

Resolving wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 2620:0:862:ed1a::1

Connecting to wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 TLS Redirect

Location: htt.ps://wikipedia.org/ [following]

--2016-07-20 21:30:40--  htt.ps://wikipedia.org/

Connecting to wikipedia.org (wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently

Location: htt.ps://www.wikipedia.org/ [following]

--2016-07-20 21:30:40--  htt.ps://www.wikipedia.org/

Resolving www.wikipedia.org (www.wikipedia.org)... 91.198.174.192, 

2620:0:862:ed1a::1


Connecting to www.wikipedia.org (www.wikipedia.org)|91.198.174.192|:443... connected.


HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: unspecified [text/html]

Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html              [<=>                 ]       0 --.-KB/s    

       ^
```

and it stops and never continues. I had to interrupt it.

The index.html I found in my home folder is totally empty BUT at the tab it says "Wikipedia"

After dig wikipedia.org the output is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> wikipedia.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15688
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wikipedia.org.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
wikipedia.org.      343 IN  A   91.198.174.192

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 193.231.252.1#53(193.231.252.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 20 21:38:59 EEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

After ping -c 3 wikipedia.org:

```
PING wikipedia.org (91.198.174.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=50.5 ms
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org (91.198.174.192): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=49.4 ms

--- wikipedia.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.342/49.475/50.594/0.954 ms
```

After ping -c 3 91.198.174.192:

```
PING 91.198.174.192 (91.198.174.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=50.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=50.7 ms
64 bytes from 91.198.174.192: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=48.2 ms

--- 91.198.174.192 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.267/49.898/50.796/1.155 ms
```

note: due to "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links"
rule of this site, I had to screw up the links to wikipedia, but you can read it anyway. Also first it showed the wget output all together so I put spaces in between the text.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely an MTU issue.  Try setting the MTU on your network interface smaller and/or add an IPTables line to do MTU clamping.  Whats probably happening is that somewhere along the line, your default 1500 byte MTU is proving too big to be transmitted - normally thanks to a VPN or VLAN or similar encapsulation of frames.  Generally an MTU of 1476 is fairly safe.

You can test this theory by setting  MTU temporarily with a command like

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

To force MTU clamping for outgoing packets.  Alternatively, if your default gateway is on eth0 for example, try

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1476
```

to set the MTU to 1476.

Comment: I have already set the MTU before in Network Manager to all sorts including 1492 and got no improvement.

Comment: Try lowering the MTU further - ie to 1476 (and make sure it takes effect). Everything you describe is consistent with an MTU issue.  If reducing the MTU does not fix the issue, someone / something - like a firewall may be playing silly buggers with your traffic - speak to your provider.

Comment: Just looking at it, another possibility might be broken IPV6 negotiation.  If you have IPv6 enabled, try turning it off and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Already spoke to my provider and they found no issue.

Comment: If you are certain its not an MTU issue, maybe the next step is to start doing packet analysis (with tcpdump or wireshark) ?

Comment: And what should I search for if I fire up a packet analysis program?

Comment: Dont know - you are looking to find out what is abnormal about the stream -3 way TCP handshake not completing? Retries/resends from one end and no response from the other?  NACK packets (negative acknowledgemnts)? Something funny in the source or dest port numbers?

Comment: Start a tcpdump, make a web request, wait until it times out and stop the capture. Upload the saved pcap file somewhere and I'll be happy to take a look over it. If you are not familiar with tcpdump, a typical command would be `tcpdump -s0 host www.wikipedia.org -w wiki_fail.pcap`

Comment: "Broken IPv6 negotiation" when the logs by OP clearly show IPv4 connections?